# MS Access pop up and modal form insert record without save button?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, ms-office

Good morning all viewers and MS access expert,

Usually when I make a table have some columns and make a pop-up form to insert records when I start to type in form inputs why if I press (X) button the form insert the record?

I'm looking for the best way to stop form inserting records as long as specific save button not pressed ? for example cancel button or Close(x) discard changes without warning?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle the form's auto update manually.

To do this, you need a module level boolean variable in the form's code behind file. This will act as flag to stop the form's auto-update.

Then on your save button you can validate the inputs and set the flag to True to allow the form to be saved.

```
'Flag
Private mIsUserUpdate As Boolean 

'Cancel auto-update
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not mIsUserUpdate Then Cancel = True
End Sub

'Save button
Private Sub ButtonSave_Click()
    If Validated then
        mIsUserUpdate = True
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your time my dear but when i do it if i press ButtonSave and try to close pop-up form warning pop-up says "you can't save this record at this time. Microsoft Access may have encountered an error while trying to save a record.. etc ? yes or no", May u tell me what is the wrong ?